# Tagging overlapping entities in html text with start and end positions

Tags: javascript, html, css

We're generating `HTML` pages dynamically and highlighting entities in text on each page. There are different classes of entities and as such different colours for highlighting each class. The method to produce the spans we employ is problematic in that it can produce improperly nested tags. For example:

```html
<p><div style="color: blue">dog<span style="color: red"> barked</div> at the intruder</span>.</p>
```

This can be corrected by a sanitization engine, to the following:

```html
<p><div style="color: blue">dog<span style="color: red"> barked</span></div><span style="color: red"> at the intruder</span>.</p>
```

However, our main problem is that we determine which entities to highlight according to their start and end char positions within that block of text. We insert tags by iterating through them in reverse (last entity in text to first in text), so that when a tag is inserted it does not interfere with any subsequent entity's start and end positions. This method does not work when there are overlapping tags.

I imagine that there are common solutions to dealing with both improperly nested tags in the tag soup and tagging overlapping entities based on char positions. I believe these issues are linked in this case. Thus, how does one produce `HTML` formatted text containing tags of potentially overlapping entities using their start and end positions?

Comment: Well, to start with you are using invalid elements like `<span1>` etc.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was just to illustrate a point. Will change it.